# Handling image onclick event using jQuery and ASP repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net, onclick, repeater

I have a repeater that includes, among other things, a text box and an image next to it. When the user enters text and clicks on the image, I want to open a modal popup.

This is for the user entering some user's last name and on image click, I search AD based on the last name and present the user with a list of AD users found and ask to select one.

I tried different methods of catching the click event but none worked. This I what I have tried (I am including both HTML image and ASP image so as not to repeat the code, but there is only one image):

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptQuestions" ClientIDMode="Static" OnItemDataBound="rptQuestions_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    ...
                    <div runat="server" id="divSUserLookup" clientidmode="static">
                        <input runat="server" id="tbSUserLookup" clientidmode="Static" type="text" class="input-small" style="width: 80%" />
                        <asp:Image runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="imgSelUser" name="imgSelUser" ImageUrl="assets/Images/user_32.png" AlternateText="Select User" />
                        <img src="assets/Images/user_32.png" alt="Select User" id="imgSelUser" />
                    </div>
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

jQuery to set up onclick; none of these get hit when image is clicked:

```
$('#imgSelUser').on('click', function (ev) {debugger       
    var lastName = $("[id*=tbSUserLookup]").val();

    if (lastName.trim() == '')
        return false;

    open_popup(lastName);
});

// Accessing control inside repeater
$("[id*=imgSelUser]").on('click', function (ev) {debugger      
    var lastName = $("[id*=tbSUserLookup]").val();

    if (lastName.trim() == '')
        return false;

    open_popup(lastName);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the `id` should be unique in the same document, so please replace the duplicate ones like `imgSelUser` & `tbSUserLookup` by common classes, e.g :

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptQuestions" ClientIDMode="Static" OnItemDataBound="rptQuestions_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    ...
                    <div runat="server" id="divSUserLookup" clientidmode="static">
                        <input runat="server" class="input-small tbSUserLookup" clientidmode="Static" type="text" style="width: 80%" />
                        <asp:Image runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" class="imgSelUser" name="imgSelUser" ImageUrl="assets/Images/user_32.png" AlternateText="Select User" />
                        <img src="assets/Images/user_32.png" alt="Select User" id="imgSelUser" />
                    </div>
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Since your DOM is generated dynamically you need to use event delegation **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** to attach the event to those elements, and use the `this` keyword to target the related elements, like :

```
$('body').on('click', '.imgSelUser', function (ev) {
    var lastName = $(this).parent().find('.tbSUserLookup').val();

    if (lastName.trim() == '')
        return false;

    open_popup(lastName);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Zakaria, now the function gets hit (actually both methods get hit). But even when I enter some value in the text box (tbSUserLookup), it always returns empty. Is this due to same symptom as image?

Comment: Each repeater item can be one of 9 different controls (radio button list, checkbox list, calendar, ...). During repeater data binding, depending on type of question, one control is displayed and others are hidden. So, for this one the 7th question shows the "Select User" text box and image. When I click it, function gets hit but textbox shows empty string unless I use $("[id*=tbSUUserLookup]")[6].value, which is not right way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I also found that if in repeater databound I set the visibility of controls not to be displayed to false (rbl.Visibile = false) instead of setting their CSS display property to "none" (rbl.Style["display"] = "none"), I can access the text box value using existing methods i had since the hidden controls are not rendered.

Comment: Glad I could help, if the answer helps you vote it up ;) and happy coding